# Running multiple GUIs in Docker using X11 forwarding

Tags: docker, x11-forwarding

I have a setup in Docker which is used to run GUI application in Docker in Ubuntu 14.04.03.

The GUI application is launched using a script file with necessary parameters. The setup works fine if the application has only one window and I can easily view the results by doing a X11-forwarding. This is the command I use to run the application

```
sudo docker run -it \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
-w /Apps/ \
--rm appsdocker:v1 \
/bin/bash -c "./run_singleGUIapp.sh param1"
```

But if the GUI has a push button that when clicked, opens up a new window, the GUI application fails to respond and after a while returns to the system prompt.

I tried running the example from this [link](http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/) which explains how to run firefox on docker using X11 forwarding. Once I search for a query on the firefox running in Docker and try 'Open in New Window' for any subsequent hit, the application works. I tried this with a presumption that it would also lead to a non-responsive behavior but it seems this is not a general case and is only persistent with my scripts.

I understand that this is very vague problem description as I cannot disclose details of the applications and the environment. Any pointers on how to handle GUI application that spawns itself would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, you don't need to write: `-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix` and `-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY`. `-v /tmp/.X11-unix \ -e DISPLAY` is enough.

Comment: I have described one solution as an answer. I can be also another problem: the second window is going to be shown on another environment, where the value of `DISPLAY` variable is not set. Try to write more about what is happening after clicking this button. Does it start a new application?

Answer (score 0):

It can be the problem with X authentication.

Try to do following. On the host:

1. `echo $DISPLAY` and remember the number (something like `:4`)
2. `xauth list` find the cookie with the number above and copy the whole line

Inside Docker:

1. `xauth add <paste the copied line>`

(As you are not attaching the container, you can pass this line to your `run` command: `/bin/bash -c "xauth add <cookie>; ./run_singleGUIapp.sh param1"`)